# TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'NoneType' with Python Boost

Tags: c++, python-3.x, python-2.7, boost, boost-python

cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(p1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

FIND_PACKAGE(PythonInterp)

if (PYTHONINTERP_FOUND)
if (UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    if (PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 3)
        FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS python${PYTHON_VERSION_SUFFIX})
        FIND_PACKAGE(PythonInterp 3)
        FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)
    else()
        FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS python)
        FIND_PACKAGE(PythonInterp)
        FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
    endif()
 else()
    if (PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 3)
        FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS 
  python${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR})
        FIND_PACKAGE(PythonInterp 3)
        FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)
    else()
        FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS 
  python${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR})
        FIND_PACKAGE(PythonInterp)
        FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
    endif()
endif()
else()
  message("Python not found")
 endif()

 message(STATUS "PYTHON_LIBRARIES = ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")
 message(STATUS "PYTHON_EXECUTABLE = ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}")
 message(STATUS "PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
 message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES = ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")

 #ENABLE_TESTING()
 INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})


  add_library(pylib SHARED pylib.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(pylib ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
 #
 # Tweaks the name of the library to match what Python expects
set_target_properties(pylib PROPERTIES SUFFIX .so)
set_target_properties(pylib PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

cmake output:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake - 
DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" 
/Users/studentuser/CLionProjects/sbmlPythonAPI
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/local/bin/python (found version "2.7.16") 
-- Boost version: 1.68.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python27
-- PYTHON_LIBRARIES = /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
-- PYTHON_EXECUTABLE = /usr/local/bin/python
-- PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS = 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr
/include/python2.7
-- Boost_LIBRARIES = /usr/local/lib/libboost_python27-mt.dylib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: 
/Users/studentuser/CLionProjects/sbmlPythonAPI/cmake-build-debug
```

Bonjour.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Bonjour
{
// Private attribute
string m_msg;

public:
// Constructor
Bonjour(string msg):m_msg(msg) { }

// Methods
void greet() { std::cout << m_msg << std::endl; }

void check_func() {cout<<"Hello! I am working"; }

// Getter/Setter functions for the attribute
void set_msg(std::string msg) { this->m_msg = msg; }
std::string get_msg() const { return m_msg; }
};
```

pylib.cpp

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "Bonjour.hpp"

using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pylib)
{
class_< Bonjour >("Bonjour", init<std::string>())
  .def("greet", &Bonjour::greet)
  .add_property("msg", &Bonjour::get_msg, &Bonjour::set_msg);
}
```

I get the error message stated in the tile when I try running

```
  from pylib import Bonjour
  b = Bonjour("He")
```

Error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-2-a019b42ef03f> in <module>()
 ----> 1 b = Bonjour("He")

 TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to show us the source file that is producing this error message, and can you show us the exact compiler error (your title is helpful, but it is not clear if "with Python Boost" is part of the error message or not).

Comment: Thanks.  And the exact text of the error message (including filenames and line numbers)?

Comment: @MartinBonner Updated

Answer (score 1):

I am using macOS, and I also encounter this `TypeError` recently! It is probably caused by linking the built `.so` file to **a different Python interpreter's** `lib/libpython2.7.dylib` file.

#### 1. **First** checkout your `.so` file by using `otool -L` command:

```sh
$ otool -L libh264decoder.so 
libh264decoder.so:
    /somepath/build/libh264decoder.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib (compatibility version 58.0.0, current version 58.35.100)
    /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libswscale.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.3.100)
    /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavutil.56.dylib (compatibility version 56.0.0, current version 56.22.100)
    /usr/local/opt/boost-python/lib/libboost_python27-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.4)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)
```

Note that this `.so` file is linked to the Python installed by MacPort, which is located at: `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python`

#### 2. **But the Python interpreter I am running** is a different one.

It's located at: `/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/py27/` (which apparently is installed by Anaconda).

#### 3. **So the solution** is to let `cmake` link to the right Python library by setting `DPYTHON_LIBRARY` varible:

```sh
$ cd build/
$ cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY="/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.dylib" ..
$ make
```

#### 4. Finally, check the result:

```sh
$ otool -L libh264decoder.so 
libh264decoder.so:
    /somepath/build/libh264decoder.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib (compatibility version 58.0.0, current version 58.35.100)
    /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libswscale.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.3.100)
    /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavutil.56.dylib (compatibility version 56.0.0, current version 56.22.100)
    /usr/local/opt/boost-python/lib/libboost_python27-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libpython2.7.dylib (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.4)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)
```

Note that the `libpython2.7.dylib`'s linking path is changed.