# Boost.Python TypeError: __init__() should return None not 'NoneType' - but no obvious linker or version problem

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, boost, anaconda

I'm building a c++ engine for python access via the boost interfaces for a python3.7 installation.  This is building for:

```
Mac OS Mojave  -  10.14.6
Python 3.7.4
Conda 4.8.3 (only crashes in a conda-built environment)
C++: clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Boost version 1.67.0
```

The python code fails (from what I can tell) *only* in `__init__` functions, with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'NoneType'
```

Other stack-overflow reports (see biblio below) and github threads suggest the typical issue is a mis-link in .dylibs between python versions, or provide no answers.  But dylib incompatibility doesn't seem to be the case here.  otool -L (or ldd) indicates library bindings are consistent and all should be well.  Here's the code and build steps.

Minimal code (with a small "check" function on python version):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <patchlevel.h>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/class.hpp>

namespace R3 {
  class DistanceType {
  public:
    DistanceType(double _val = 0) : val(_val) {}
    double get() const { return val; }
    void set(double _val) { val = _val; }
  private:
    double val;
  };
  void pyversion() {
    int hexversion = PY_VERSION_HEX;
    std::cout << "compiled with python version: " << PY_VERSION
      << " (hex version code) " << std::hex << std::setw(8) << hexversion << '\n';
  }
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(simplepython) {
  using namespace boost::python;

  class_<R3::DistanceType>("DistanceType", init<double>())
    .add_property("value", &R3::DistanceType::get, &R3::DistanceType::set)
  ;

  boost::python::def("pyversion", R3::pyversion);
}
```

Here are the results from building and running the code:

```
>: g++ -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -O2 -fPIC -std=c++11  -Iinclude   -c -o objs/simplepython.o src/simplepython.cpp
>: g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/anaconda3/lib -shared -o lib/simplepython.so objs/simplepython.o -L/opt/anaconda3/lib -Llib -lpython3.7m -ldl -framework CoreFoundation -lboost_python37 -lboost_numpy37
>: cd lib
>: python -c 'import simplepython as R3; R3.pyversion(); R3.DistanceType(1)'
compiled with python version: 3.7.4 (hex version code)  30704f0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'NoneType'
```

Bibliography - related stack-overflow issue reports:

[TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'NoneType' with Python Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55238021/typeerror-init-should-return-none-not-nonetype-with-python-boost)

[Is this Boost::Python (Python 3.7) error "__init__() should return None, not 'NoneType'" a linking problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54708598/is-this-boostpython-python-3-7-error-init-should-return-none-not-no)

[Boost.Python __init__() should return None, not 'NoneType'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437769/boost-python-init-should-return-none-not-nonetype)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the error is with the static linked library, libpython<*version*>.  For compatibility with conda and non-conda environments, a c++/boost build should resolve these symbols dynamically.  The following solved it for me:

In your link line, replace `-lpython<version>m` with `-undefined dynamic_lookup.`

**CMake**:

The link line is available in `/build/mybinary/CMakeFiles/myextension_py.dir/link.txt`. For now it seems that the link command has to be manually edited in CMake version `3.17.2`.

**NOTE**:

If you use `$(shell python3-config --libs)` to derive the `-l` paths, it may defeat the solution: prior to version 3.8 it includes `-lpython<version>m`. Due to this inconsistency I simply use my own expanded data for the time being.

**Credits**:

Thanks to [Nehal J Wani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1005215/nehal-j-wani) who originally reported this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54708598/is-this-boostpython-python-3-7-error-init-should-return-none-not-no?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Thanks [newkid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4782513/newkid) for the CMake edit - I copied it here from the other posting.