# __init__() should return None, not 'NoneType' for python module using boost_python

Tags: python, c++, boost-python, juce

I am using python3 and `[Renderman][1]` compiled by myself.

This library is using `boost_python` which make python library by cpp.

`test.py`

```
import librenderman as rm     
engine = rm.RenderEngine(44100,512,512)
```

I have error like this

```
$python test.py
JUCE v5.2.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    engine = rm.RenderEngine(44100,512,512)
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'NoneType'
```

I googled around and found it is because of python 2/3 diffrences.

then checked linked libraries

```
$otool -L librenderman.so 
librenderman.so:
    /usr/local/lib/librenderman.so.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/libpython3.7m.dylib (compatibility version 3.7.0, current version 3.7.0)
    @rpath/libboost_python37.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1000.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AVFoundation (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AVKit.framework/Versions/A/AVKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 164.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 23.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudioKit.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudioKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/Versions/A/CoreMedia (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMIDI.framework/Versions/A/CoreMIDI (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 69.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore (compatibility version 1.2.0, current version 1.11.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 610.3.7)
    @rpath/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.60.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 2022.20.117)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 54.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1770.255.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics (compatibility version 64.0.0, current version 1463.2.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1122.11.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1770.255.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

I think python3 module is linked correctly.

Where and how should I fix this problem??

I am familliar with python3 though, not familliar with `python2` and `boost-python`

Any suggestion helps.

`RenderEngine.h`

```
/*
  ==============================================================================

    RenderEngine.h
    Created: 19 Feb 2017 9:47:15pm
    Author:  tollie

  ==============================================================================
*/

#ifndef RENDERENGINE_H_INCLUDED
#define RENDERENGINE_H_INCLUDED

#include <random>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "Maximilian/maximilian.h"
#include "Maximilian/libs/maxiFFT.h"
#include "Maximilian/libs/maxiMFCC.h"
#include "../JuceLibraryCode/JuceHeader.h"

using namespace juce;

typedef std::vector<std::pair<int, float>>  PluginPatch;
typedef std::vector<std::array<double, 13>> MFCCFeatures;

class RenderEngine
{
public:
    RenderEngine (int sr,
                  int bs,
                  int ffts) :
        sampleRate(sr),
        bufferSize(bs),
        fftSize(ffts),
        plugin(nullptr)
    {
        maxiSettings::setup (sampleRate, 1, bufferSize);
    }

    virtual ~RenderEngine()
    {
        if (plugin != nullptr)
        {
            plugin->releaseResources();
            delete plugin;
        }
    }


    bool loadPlugin (const std::string& path);

    void setPatch (const PluginPatch patch);

    const PluginPatch getPatch();

    void renderPatch (const uint8  midiNote,
                      const uint8  midiVelocity,
                      const double noteLength,
                      const double renderLength);

    const MFCCFeatures getMFCCFrames();

    const MFCCFeatures getNormalisedMFCCFrames (const std::array<double, 13>& mean,
                                                const std::array<double, 13>& variance);

    const std::vector<double> getRMSFrames();

    const size_t getPluginParameterSize();

    const String getPluginParametersDescription();

    bool overridePluginParameter (const int   index,
                                  const float value);

    bool removeOverridenParameter (const int index);

    const std::vector<double> getAudioFrames();

    bool writeToWav(const std::string& path);

private:
    void fillAudioFeatures (const AudioSampleBuffer& data,
                            maxiFFT&                 fft);

    void ifTimeSetNoteOff (const double& noteLength,
                           const double& sampleRate,
                           const int&    bufferSize,
                           const uint8&  midiChannel,
                           const uint8&  midiPitch,
                           const uint8&  midiVelocity,
                           const int&    currentBufferIndex,
                           MidiBuffer&   bufferToNoteOff);

    void fillAvailablePluginParameters (PluginPatch& params);

    double               sampleRate;
    int                  bufferSize;
    int                  fftSize;
    maxiMFCC             mfcc;
    AudioPluginInstance* plugin;
    PluginPatch          pluginParameters;
    PluginPatch          overridenParameters;
    MFCCFeatures         mfccFeatures;
    std::vector<double>  processedMonoAudioPreview;
    std::vector<double>  rmsFrames;
    double               currentRmsFrame;
};


#endif  // RENDERENGINE_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61463744/boost-python-typeerror-init-should-return-none-not-nonetype-but-no-ob ?

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried `In your link line, replace -lpython<version>m with -undefined dynamic_lookup.` from that article, and it works like a charm.

Comment: glad it worked, I will flag this as a dupe of that question then

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boost.Python TypeError: \_\_init\_\_() should return None not 'NoneType' - but no obvious linker or version problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61463744/boost-python-typeerror-init-should-return-none-not-nonetype-but-no-ob)